# Series convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

So I have a test next week and I tried to solve this question but I do not know how.

Regarding $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{xn}{e^{nx}}$

Proof that it is Uniform convergence in $[\delta , \infty)\ \  \forall \delta > 0$

Proof that it is not Uniform convergence in $[0 , \infty)$

So I know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{e^n}$ is convergent.

I know that $\forall x \geq 1 \ \ \frac{xn}{e^{nx}} \leq \frac{xn}{e^{n}}$ and I know that $ \ x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{e^n}$ is convergent therefore according to

Weierstrass M-test I know that $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{xn}{e^{nx}}$ is Uniform convergence.

But what about $x<1$ ?

How can I proof that ?

And how can I proof that it is not Uniform convergence in $[0,\infty)$ ?

Thanks in advanced !!

Answer (score 2):

$$\forall\,x\in [\delta>0,\infty)\;,\;\;\frac{xn}{e^{nx}}\le\frac{xn}{e^{\delta n}}=:a_n$$

and

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+1)x}{e^{(n+1)\delta}}\frac{e^{n\delta}}{nx}=\frac{n+1}n\frac1{e^\delta}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac{1}{e^\delta}<1\iff e^\delta>1\iff\delta >0$$

So apply Weierstrass' s M-test to the series of the rightmost side in the first line and get that we have absolute and uniform convergence for all x in the wanted interval. no matter whether $\,\delta >1\;$ or not.

Comment: Oh you are right !! What about the case of $[0,\infty) \ $ ?

Comment: I know that in order to proof that it is not uniform convergence I will have to find a $ \epsilon > 0 \ \ n,m \in \mathbb{N} \ $ and $ \ x \in [0,\infty)$ so that $|\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+m} \frac{xk}{e^{kx}}| \geq \epsilon$ but I need a little help here

Comment: someone ? please

Answer (score 1):

To prove that the convergence in $[0,\infty)$ is not uniform, you can argue by contradiction: consider the sequence $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$. If $f_n(x)=nxe^{-nx}$ and $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^nf_k$, then $x_n\to 0$, so if the series is uniformly convergent to $s$, you have that $s_n(x_n)\to s(0)$. But, $s(0)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(0)=0$, so $s_n(x_n)\to 0$. But, all the $f_n$ are nonnegative, so $$s_n(x_n)\geq f_n\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=e^{-1},$$ therefore $s_n(x_n)$ does not converge to $0$, contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

$S= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{xn}{e^{nx}}$

$ \frac{S}{e^{x}}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{xn}{e^{(n+1)x}}$

$ S(1-\frac{1}{e^{x}})= \frac{x}{e^{x}{(1-\frac{1}{e^x})}}$
 $=>S= \frac{x e^x}{(e^x -1)^2} $
as $\lim_{x \to 0} => S\to\infty $
but for $ x> 0 $ it is defined finitely